# When using webview in Android is there a way to redirect a specific url?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to intercept urls in an Android webview, and if a url matches, have it redirect to another page? Basically, I want to auto-redirect certain pages to ones specifically for that app.

I couldnt find anything specific for how to do this and searching Google isnt helping.

Thanks,

Comment: Set a WebViewClient for your WebView.

Override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method to intercept URLs.

After matching Regex, redirect those to certain pages to ones specifically for your needs.

Comment: @AdarshSahu Can you give a code example of intercepting and redirecting a url so that I can see how to do this in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
binding.webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
            view.loadUrl(request.url.toString())
            return false
        }
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
            val url = request?.url.toString()

            if (shouldRedirect(url)) {
                // Redirect to another page
                view?.loadUrl("www.google.com")
                return true
            }
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
        }

        private fun shouldRedirect(url: String): Boolean {
            return url.contains("your_keyword")
        }
    }
```